# Visual Basic Script - get user password?

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, passwords, credentials

I am writing a script and part of it needs to know the password of whatever user is logged in. The problem is I cannot figure out a way to get the password. I can get the username with -

```
Set oWshshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wscript.echo oWshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("Username=%UserName%")
```

I was hoping it is possible to do something similar with the password. Is it possible to get the password of the user currently logged in? If so, how? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This couldn't possibly be used for evil

Comment: This is hopefully impossible.  If you figure it out, let me know--I plan on selling it for A KING'S BOUNTY!

Comment: I would really hope this is never possible or I am moving to Linux. Even if it was, I would hope you would get an encrypted version of it, not clear text.

Comment: For the record, I'm just following orders here and felt like I should ask stack to confirm that it is not possible.

Comment: Could you explain what it is your are trying to achieve? Perhaps there is another way of going about the problem you are solving, which does not include attempting to get the logged in user's password.

Comment: I want to verify password complexity for every user that is created. The machine won't have Windows 7 Professional so I can't edit the password complexity in local security policy. I was told to try and make a logon script to check it...I know, it sounds like a crude method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is completely impossible; Windows never stores passwords in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Technically Windows can be configured to store passwords using reversible encryption (although not in plaintext). That still is a really, *REALLY* bad idea, though.

If you only want to verify password complexity: you should be able to do that with a [custom password filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) when users change their password.